# Card Mismatch & Card Match (Memory Game)

Tags: javascript

I am in a computer class and for a project, I need to create a game. For my game, I am trying to make it to where when I click on my card, and it matches another, it will disappear, and when it **doesn't** match then it will delay and then turn over. This is all I could make so far out of the knowledge I have of coding, but there's a few issues. When I click on the first button, then the second matching button, it is normal and will give you +1 score and then disappear. But if I click on the second matching button, it will just make both buttons disappear, instead of waiting for the other button to be clicked first. Ex.:

```
function disappear() {
  onEvent("btn1" && "btn7", "click", function( ) {
    hideElement("btn1");
    hideElement("btn7");
    score++;
    win();
  });
}
```

So I can click btn1 and THEN btn7, then it will disappear. BUT if I click btn 7, they both just disappear without needing to match.
I haven't been able to figure this out so I haven't started making the buttons mismatch then turn over

This is my entire coding for the game:
https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/caQfCo-bnBc9jVYNdHG0Bvic2NR_lcltdZ2d7504-Rs

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question in text form (properly formatted, or as an executable snippet in cases where that makes sense), not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: You should rather not go with an approach that tries to react on clicks of specific combinations of buttons to begin with. Have _one_ click handler, for _all_ the buttons. Use a variable to remember which one was clicked previously - so that you can decide whether the current click was for the matching card, or a different one.